# Java conditionals (if clauses set-up)

Tags: java

What I'm trying to figure out is when user puts `age < 18` I want program to stop. Same idea with "Jack" part below that If user named jack I want it to stop also.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Newbie
{
  public static void main(String[] arg)
  {
    Scanner qk = new Scanner(System.in);
    int age;
    String ans;

    System.out.println("How old are you?");
    age = qk.nextInt();

    if(age < 18)
      System.out.println(age + " is too young!");           

    if(age > 18)
      System.out.println("You can enter. What is your name?");

    Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);
    ans = q.nextLine();

    if(ans.equals("Jack"))
    System.out.println("Jack, you are not allowed to use this program.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a `boolean` field to keep track of whether or not the user is authorized to use the program.

**Example:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Newbie
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
      boolean authorized = true;
      Scanner qk = new Scanner(System.in);
      int Age;
      String ans;

      System.out.println("How old are you?");
      Age=qk.nextInt();
      in.nextLine(); // clear newline char from the buffer
      if(Age < 18) {
        System.out.println ( Age +" is too young! " ); 
        authorized = false;         
      }
      else { // else statement fixes logic error
        System.out.println ( " You can enter. What is your name ? " );
        ans=qk.nextLine();
        if (ans.equals("Jack")) {
          System.out.println ( "Jack, you are not allowed to use this program " );
          authorized = false;         
        }
      }
      if(authorized) {
        // Do program stuff here
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Well... if i don't use the second scanner, program skips the answer of "What is your name?" and ends

Comment: @AtakanBal you need to clear the `\n` newline character from the Scanner buffer I have update my answer to fix that issue!

Answer (score 2):

You can write `return;` to terminate execution of the current method.

Comment: Of course this doesn't always mean the program will also stop.

Comment: A very miting suggestion and bad programming style. I should know. I'm a lousy programmer... :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `System.exit(0)` to stop the Programm where ever you are,
`return;` just terminate the method.

Answer (score 0):

put a "return;"
after the if ( but place what you want to come after the if in curly braces {}

since you are inside the main function, the return will just exit the function, and therfore exit the program

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stop if the user enters `"Jack"`, do like this:

```
if (ans.equals("Jack")) {
    System.out.println ( "Jack, you are not allowed to use this program " );
    System.exit();
}
```

Comment: As the others write, using return does the same in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Exiting the program execution by `return` works in this case, because you only have a very simple `main` setup. If you want to stop execution independently of what method you're in, use the following.

```
if(age < 18)
  System.exit(0);
```

In your case, it would be like this.

```
if(age < 18){
  System.out.println(age +" is too young!");
  System.exit(0);
}
```

Besides that, you've got a logical error in your code. What happenes if the user enters *18*? He/she is still allowed in but has nothing that tells him/her that. Use this condition instead.

```
if(age < 18){
  System.out.println(age +" is too young!");
  System.exit(0);
} else {
  System.out.println("You can enter. What is your name?");
}
```